# How best to initialize python's random module within a function

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I'm looking for some info around generating as random of number as possible when the random module is embedded within a function like so:

```
import random as rd

def coinFlip()
    flip = rd.random()

    if flip > .5: 
        return "Heads"
    else:
        return "Tails"

main()
    for i in range(1000000):
        print(coinFlip())
```

**Edit: Ideally the above script would always yield different results therefore limiting my ability to use random.seed()**

Does the random module embedded within a function initialize with a new seed each time the function is called? (Instead of using the previous generated random number as the seed.)

If so...

Is the default initialization on system time exact enough to pull a truly random number considering that the system times in the for loop here would be so close together or maybe even the same (depending on the precision of the system time.)

Is there a way to initialize a random module outside of the function and have the function pull the next random number (so to avoid multiple initializations.)

Any other more pythonic ways to accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `random.seed()`  if you want to initialize the pseudo-random number generator

you can have a look [here](https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/)

> If you don’t initialize the pseudo-random number generator using a
>   random.seed (), internally random generator call the seed function and
>   use current system current time value as the seed value. That’s why
>   whenever we execute random.random() we always get a different value

if you want to always have a diff number than you should not bother with initializing the random module since internally, the random module it is using by default the current system time(which is always diff).
just use :

```
from random import random 

def coinFlip()

    if random() > .5: 
        return "Heads"
    else:
        return "Tails"
```

to make more clear, the random module it is not initializing each time it is used, only at import time, so every time you call random.random() you have the next number which is guaranteed to be different

Comment: I don't think this would work (especially if put into the function as well) because then the random numbers will generate identically every time this script is run. Moreover, if random.seed() is placed in the function itself ahead of rd.random(), then the generated random number would always be the same. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yep, usually, this is the reason you may want to initialize the random module, to have the same "random numbers", if you do not want to have the same random then you should not initialize the random module, so you want to have always diff numbers?

Comment: Correct. (I'll edit the question to include that fact. Sorry I didn't initially.)

Comment: maybe now, my answer is more fit for your issue

Comment: by the way, to make more clear, the random module it is not initializing each time it is used, only at import time, so every time you call random.random() you have the next number which is guaranteed to be different

Comment: Ah ha. Your point about random initializing **at import** is actually the answer I was looking for. It answers the portion of my question that reads, "Does the random module embedded within a function initialize with a new seed each time the function is called?" If you change your answer once more to include that, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

> This module implements pseudo-random number generators for various distributions.
>
> [..]
>
> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.
>
> <sub>https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html</sub>

The `random` module is a *Pseudo-Random Number Generator*. All PRNGs are entirely deterministic and have *state*. Meaning, if the PRNG is in the same state, the next "random" number will always be the same. As the above paragraph explains, your `rd.random()` call is really a call to an implicitly instantiated `Random` object.

So:

> Does the random module embedded within a function initialize with a new seed each time the function is called?

*No.*

> Is there a way to initialize a random module outside of the function and have the function pull the next random number (so to avoid multiple initializations.)

You don't need to avoid multiple initialisation, as it's not happening. You *can* instantiate your own `Random` object if you want to control the state exactly.

> `class random.Random([seed])`
>   Class that implements the default pseudo-random number generator used by the random module.

> `random.seed(a=None, version=2)`
>   Initialize the random number generator. If `a` is omitted or `None`, the current system time is used. [..]

So, the implicitly instantiated `Random` object uses the system time as initial seed ([read further](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) though), and from there will keep state. So each time you start your Python instance, it will be seeded differently, but will be seeded only once.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Keeping state was the critical piece that I was looking for. I marked rusu_ro1 answer correct because, as you can see in the comments there, he also enlightened me as to the state point. I very much appreciate your work and effort here!